# Source Model Radio Button in system.xml custom module

Tags: magento2, backend, system.xml

I am developing a custom module in Magento 2.0.9 and writing the system.xml file to allow users to make some settings from backend.

Now I need to show a Radio button in custom module backend settings section.
This is what I wrote in system.xml

```
<field id="box_small_left_h_alignment" translate="label" type="radio" sortOrder="31" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Horizontal Alignment</label>
    <source_model>SG\Slider\Model\Backend\Options\HorizontalAlignment</source_model>
</field>
```

And this is the source model:

```
<?php

namespace SG\Slider\Model\Backend\Options;

class HorizontalAlignment implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface {

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [['value' => 'left', 'label' => __('Left')], ['value' => 'right', 'label' => __('Right')],];
    }

}
```

Doing in this way no error are thrown in the backend but my radio field has no options. What am I missing?

Comment: Try to delete the last comma in this instruction: `return [['value' => 'left', 'label' => __('Left')], ['value' => 'right', 'label' => __('Right')],];`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `radios` instead of `radio` as field type.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/84214)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand you.. my answer provides a solution to the question.
The issue is due to the use of `radio` instead of `radios`; I've also tested it and it works fine.